# SD card works perfectly in macOS, but not in Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, catalina, sd-card

Recently I bought a new microSD card - Transcend UHS-I microSD 300S. It's microSDHC 32 GB card, I've also formatted it in exFAT. And I'm also using a 13-inch MacBook Pro, Early 2011 model.

The problem is - I need it to work with Windows installed on the laptop. In macOS it works just fine, I can reformat it any time. But it does not work in Windows 10 on the same MacBook. It shows up **only when I reboot from macOS 10.15 to Windows 10 with microSD card inserted in the microSD-to-SD adapter**, and when I disconnect it, I can't connect it back - it just doesn't work before I reboot.

I've tried reconnecting the card many times, tried reinstalling Broadcom SD drivers from Boot Camp Support Software 5.1, resetting SMC and NVRAM - still the same problem. The other cards are working just fine, and the same Trancsend card actually works in Windows on other laptop - Acer Aspire 3830TG.

So, how can I fix this? This is very strange problem.

Comment: One missing bit of info from your question, "What is the format of the drive? HFS, APFS, FAT, NTFS?" Open disk utility and find out and add that info **to your original question (not as a comment)**

Comment: I thought it didn't matter so much, but just for info: the format is exFAT, it can be seen by both macOS and Windows

Comment: Please add that info to the original question

Comment: I've done this already.

Comment: Also, I've just tried to reinstall Windows now, there's still the same issue

Comment: Does this happen after sleep?  I have 2013 and 2015 MBP and in both SD card reader disappears after sleep and will not work again until rebooting.  You can try hibernating instead - see [Boot Camp Windows 10 Win10 SD card](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8038937).  Unfortunately I have to sleep to stop [System and System Interrupts- high cpu utilization](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6598184) so it is one or the other for me - overheating and SD card or normal temps and no SD card.

Comment: The problem is that SD card reader is showing up normally (Broadcom SD Host Adapter or something), the microSD card inside an adapter just won't show up. Even after reboot it doesn't connect the card, although the SD reader is visible in the Device Manager.